# Spring Boot Security : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Below is security config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        CustomAuthProvider authProvider = new CustomAuthProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/favicon.ico", "/signup", "/cdn.jsdelivr.net", "/cdn.jsdelivr.net/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
                .authenticationManager(new ProviderManager(List.of(authProvider()))).csrf().disable().build();

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

Here is my DaoAuthenticationProvider:

```
@Service
public class CustomAuthProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    

    @Autowired
    private AuthUserRepo authUserRepo;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        logger.info("CustomAuthProvider authentication ::::: {} ", authentication);
        logger.info("CustomAuthProvider authentication.getPrincipal() ::::: {} ",
                authentication.getPrincipal().toString());

        final String name = authentication.getName();

        logger.info("CustomAuthenticationProvider ::::: " + authentication.getCredentials().toString());

        final String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        logger.info("CustomAuthenticationProvider ::::: " + name);
        if ((name == null || password == null)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password");
        }

        Optional<AuthUser> authUser = authUserRepo.findByEmail(name);

        if (authUser.isEmpty()) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password");

        }

        final Authentication result = super.authenticate(authentication);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authUser.get(),
                result.getCredentials().toString(), result.getAuthorities());

    }

}
```

Here is my CustomUserDetailService:

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    AuthUserRepo authUserRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.info("CustomUserDetailService -> UserName :::: {}", username);

        Optional<AuthUser> savedUser = authUserRepo.findByEmail(username);
        if (savedUser.isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username: " + username);

        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(savedUser.get().getEmail(),
                savedUser.get().getPassword(), true, true, true, true, getAuthorities());
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> roles = Arrays.asList("Associate", "Manager");

        for (String string : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(string));

        }

        return authorities;
    }

}
```

I am not  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set. I have set UserdetailService in my security config.

Below is exception stacktrace:

```
M 16-Sept-2022 02:14:32.372 [restartedMain] ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication:824] - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuthProvider' defined in file [/Users/itadminsalesken/Downloads/spring5login/target/classes/security/spring5login/conf/CustomAuthProvider.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at security.spring5login.Spring5loginApplication.main(Spring5loginApplication.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.doAfterPropertiesSet(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:85)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Its because you are usin `loginForm` which will (if you read the docs) create a AuthenticationProvider for you automatically. Why you decided to create your own i have no idea.

Comment: I am looking for a custom login page and autheticate user via JDBC

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried initializing UserDetailsService in securityConfig class with `@Bean`? It might have causing problems since `@Configuration` beans are created before `@Service` beans.

Comment: Also why do you have @Service annotation in CustomAuthProvider when you create bean in config. If i understand this well you're duplicating beans. I don't know how this doesn't throw any errors with this. Maybe because there's DaoAuthProvider instead of Custom in the config.

Comment: @Bean
 public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
  return new CustomUserDetailService();
 } I have tried but same error